# How to deploy to a specific instance

Tags: google-cloud-console

How can I specify on which instance I want my app to run ?

After `gcloud preview app deploy`, a new instance is automatically created for that new version. If I create a new instance (one with more CPU than those created automatically) it just stays idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `app.yaml`:

```
resources:
  cpu: 8
  memory_gb: 64
```